# A Polish space which is not locally compact

Tags: general-topology

I want to find an example of Polish space which is not locally compact. I am thinking about the space of all continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $R$, endowed with the metric $d(f,g) = \sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$.

I know this space is complete. And by Weierstrass Approximation Theorem, all the polynomials with rationals coefficients are a countable dense subset of it, so it is Polish.

Then suppose the function $f=0$ has a compact neighbourhood, then there exists $r >0$ such that all the continuous functions bounded by $r$ are in the neighbourhood. But then we can define a sequence of functions such as $g_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0, x<a_n\\ r,x>a_{n+1}\\r \frac{x-a_n}{a_{n+1} - a_n}, a_n \leq x\leq a_{n+1}\end{cases}$, where $(a_n)_n$ increases to(but never reaches) 1. Then for $m,n$ different, we have $d(g_n, g_m) = r$, so the function $f=0$ has no compact neighbourhood. Therefore this space is not locally compact.

Did I miss something?

Comment: That works. If you have it, you could also appeal to Riesz' theorem that a topological vector space is locally compact if and only if it is finite-dimensional.

Comment: As an aside, [the Baire space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)) $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is also a non-locally-compact Polish space.  (It is not too difficult to show that all compact subsets of it have empty interior.)

Comment: Does Locally Compact, Separable $\Rightarrow$ Polish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, the example works.

More generally, an infinite dimensional separable complete normed space would do the job (Riesz theorem prevents local compact).

Comment: Is it necessary that the normed space is infinite-dimensional?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it is locally compact. It's added now.